# Different forms of Tangent Angle Addition Identity

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification

I am trying to derive the tangent angle addition identity:
$$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}$$
by the argument shown here:

[image]

While I can arrive at the correct identity algebraically and using trig ratios in a geometric diagram proof, I'm confused about why I cannot substitute 1 for the numerator, i.e.
$$\tan(x+y) = \frac{1}{1-\tan x\tan y}$$ as I am using a unit square and $1 = \tan x+\tan y$. I tried graphing these to compare and evaluating values but they are definitely not equal.

Is there a general rule for making substitutions in diagram proofs like this one? If I cannot use $1$ in the numerator to represent $\tan x+\tan y$, then why am I allowed to use $1$ in the denominator?

Comment: While you've declared the bottom edge of the rectangle to be $1$, there's nothing that would suggest that the rectangle is a *square*, so, you can't make the substitution $\tan x+\tan y\to 1$. (BTW: I appreciate seeing people approach trig identities geometrically. :)

Comment: Ahhh of course! I feel so silly after reading your comment! Is there any way I can mark it as the answer to this question?

Comment: Write an answer yourself, and I'll be happy to upvote it. :)

Answer (score 3):

@Blue pointed out that while I have defined the bottom edge of my rectangle as 1, there is nothing in the diagram to suggest that it is a square. Thus, I cannot set its height as 1 and cannot assert that $1 = tanx+tany$! I am embarrassed as this has been bothering me for several days; finding this simple solution was very satisfying. Thanks, @Blue!

Comment: +1. As a self-proclaimed ["trigonographer"](https://trigonography.com/2015/09/28/angle-sum-and-difference-for-sine-and-cosine/), I'm a firm believer in the benefits of diagrammatic proofs. But we all have to be vigilant not to read *too much* into our diagrams. :)